# Computing the pdf of two random variables with different supports.

Tags: probability, robust-statistics

I am fairly new to stack exchange, but I need some guidance on the following problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent, continuous random variables described by probability density functions $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$.

$f_{X}(x) \sim Gamma(n+1,1)$.

$f_{Y}(y) \sim p(1-|y|) + \frac{(1-p)}{\pi(1+y^2)}\: p\in[0,1]\; s.t.\; p+(1-p) = 1$.

Given the above definitions compute the probability density function of $Z = XY$.

The formula for the product of two distributions is the following:

$f_Z(z) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f_X \left( x \right)  f_Y \left( z/x \right)  \frac{1}{|x|}\, dx.$

The integral is quite involved and I have made approaches using numerical integration with no luck.

To clear up the support confusion:

- Gamma has support on $x \in (0, \infty).$
- The first half of the mixture has support on $y\in[-1,1]$.
- The second half of the mixture has support on $y\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

Feel free to correct any of these definitions if they seem odd.  I am an undergraduate doing research on heavy-tailed ICA and am "fairly" new to some of this work.

Edit: I believe I have made some parts of my question a bit more clear.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, @Blaine!! My tip is to write the support as an indicator function, i.e.  $\mathbb{I}_{A}(x)$ a function that is unit if $x \in A$ and is 0 if not. Then you'll be able to have the new support, with the properties of indicator functions.

Comment: It is not the product of two distibutions but the **product of 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$**, which has not for its distribution the product of distributions od $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @YetAnotheruser Your tip is not bas but basically, the problem of the OP is a misunderstanding of what a random variable is when he says "The typical formula for the product of two distributions does not apply here due to X and Y having different supports." It applies because **one can always multiply two random variables** ! I think there is a mixing between"range" and "support".

Comment: Yes, a big improvement in your way to describe your (not simple) issue. I have taken the liberty to modify your title.